# VK api keyboard

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Как добавить клавиатуру для выбора после третьего сообщения и проигрывалось два варианта в зависимости от того, что выбрал пользователь (Да/Нет)? Клавиатура при этом должна убрать после ответа.

```
for word in filterContacts:
        if word.lower() in text.lower():
            if objectid == 6:
                api.messages.send(access_token=token, user_id=str(user_id), message=messageContacts, random_id=random.getrandbits(64))
                api.messages.send(access_token=token, user_id=str(user_id), message=message2, random_id=random.getrandbits(64))
                api.messages.send(access_token=token, user_id=str(user_id), message=message3, random_id=random.getrandbits(64))
                return 'ok'
                keyboard = VkKeyboard(one_time=True)
                keyboard.add_button('Да', color=VkKeyboardColor.POSITIVE)
                keyboard.add_button('Нет', color=VkKeyboardColor.NEGATIVE)
```

Таким способом клавиатура не добавляется (нужный импорт для клавиатуры сделан).

Ниже смог добавить клавиатуру к сообщению, но при нажатии на кнопки ничего не происходит, как можно запустить обработку кнопки?

```
    keyboard_1 = VkKeyboard(one_time=True, inline=True)
keyboard_1.add_callback_button(
        label="Нет",
        color=VkKeyboardColor.POSITIVE,
        payload={"type": "show_snackbar", "text": "Благодарим за внимание!"},
    )
keyboard_1.add_line()
keyboard_1.add_callback_button(
        label="Да",
        color=VkKeyboardColor.NEGATIVE,
        payload={"type": "open_link", "link": "ССЫЛКА"},
    )

api.messages.send(access_token=token, user_id=str(user_id), message=message3, keyboard=keyboard_1.get_keyboard(), random_id=random.getrandbits(64))
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы используете callback кнопки, после нажатия вк отправляет событие message_event которое вам нужно отлавливать. И в нем уже производить действия, например show_snackbar. Для этого используйте messages.sendMessageEventAnswer

В документации все прекрасно описано, изучайте https://dev.vk.com/api/bots/development/keyboard#Callback